# Accessing javax.ws.rs.core.Response header in a JSP

Tags: jsp, jersey, jax-rs

Given the following in a JAX-RS resource using Jersey:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
...
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("myAttribute", "value");
return Response.ok(new Viewable("myJsp.jsp", map))
    .build();
```

What is the correct way to access *myAttribute* from the jsp?
Have tried this, but it returns null:

```
console.log("<%= response.getHeader("myAttribute") %>");
```

Note that the JSP page is included in a parent page using `<jsp:include>.`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the [Jersey MVC documentation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/mvc.html#d0e15608), you could access it with:

```
console.log("${model.myAttribute}");
```

or

```
console.log("${it.myAttribute}");
```

Comment: That just prints out 0 in the console

Comment: Don't know if is an issue, but the jsp page is included in a parent page via <jsp:include>. Will update question.

Comment: Can you test `<p>${it.myAttribute}</p>` on the parent page?

Comment: Thanks. The problem was not the page include - it was that I had a new line character in the value ('\n'), which presumably is not acceptable as a response parameter value.